# How to have fixed table headers that are aligned with the rows? reactjs, nodejs

Tags: node.js, reactjs

How would I implement table headers that are fixed when scrolling down or up. I currently have the tables that are scrollable but the table headers dissapear. I would like the table headers to be fixed. I am fetching data from jira by using a rest api, and the data is random, so it would automatically fix the width of each table header/table row/ table cell but how would i make the table header stay fixed when scrolling down?It currently looks like this:

[image]

```
const WorkInProgressHLEsDataFilter = () => {
      const { WorkInProgressHLESearchTerm, WIPHLEsData } = this.state;

      return WIPHLEsData
        .filter(issue => {
          return issue.supNumber && issue.supNumber.toLowerCase().indexOf(WorkInProgressHLESearchTerm.toLowerCase()) !== -1 ||
          issue.Airline && issue.Airline.toLowerCase().indexOf(WorkInProgressHLESearchTerm.toLowerCase()) !== -1 ||
          issue.Product && issue.Product.toLowerCase().indexOf(WorkInProgressHLESearchTerm.toLowerCase()) !== -1 ||
          issue.Title && issue.Title.toLowerCase().indexOf(WorkInProgressHLESearchTerm.toLowerCase()) !== -1 ||
          issue.Status && issue.Status.toLowerCase().indexOf(WorkInProgressHLESearchTerm.toLowerCase()) !== -1 || 
          issue.DateHLERequestReceived && issue.DateHLERequestReceived.toLowerCase().indexOf(WorkInProgressHLESearchTerm.toLowerCase()) !== -1 || 
          issue.HLEDevDays && issue.HLEDevDays.toLowerCase().indexOf(WorkInProgressHLESearchTerm.toLowerCase()) !== -1 || 
          issue.HLEClientDays && issue.HLEClientDays.toLowerCase().indexOf(WorkInProgressHLESearchTerm.toLowerCase()) !== -1 ||
          issue.DateHLESent && issue.DateHLESent.toLowerCase().indexOf(WorkInProgressHLESearchTerm.toLowerCase()) !== -1 || 
          issue.DateHLEApprovedRefused && issue.DateHLEApprovedRefused.toLowerCase().indexOf(WorkInProgressHLESearchTerm.toLowerCase()) !== -1 || 
          issue.Comments && issue.Comments.toLowerCase().indexOf(WorkInProgressHLESearchTerm.toLowerCase()) !== -1
        })
        .map(issue => (

          <tr key={issue.id}>
            <td><a target="_blank" href={"jira.com/browse/" + issue.supNumber}>{issue.supNumber} </a> </td> 
            <td>{issue.Airline}</td>
            <td>{issue.Product}</td>
            <td>{issue.Title}</td>
            <td>{issue.Status}</td>
            <td>{issue.DateHLERequestReceived}</td>
            <td>{issue.HLEDevDays}</td>
            <td>{issue.HLEClientDays}</td>
            <td>{issue.DateHLESent}</td>
            <td>{issue.DateHLEApprovedRefused}</td>
            <td>{issue.Comments}</td>
            <td>
                      <Link to={{
                        pathname: '/WorkInProgressHLEs/supNumber?=' + issue.supNumber,
                        state: {
                          supNumber: issue.supNumber,
                          HLEDevDays: issue.HLEDevDays,
                          HLEClientDays:issue.HLEClientDays,
                          DateHLESent: issue.DateHLESent,
                          DateHLEApprovedRefused: issue.DateHLEApprovedRefused,
                          Comments: issue.Comments,
                          Key: this.state.key,
                          Title: issue.Title
                        }
                      }}>
                      <ButtonToolbar>

                      <Button bsSize="xsmall" bsStyle="primary"> EDIT</Button>

                      </ButtonToolbar>
                      </Link>
             </td>
          </tr>
        ));
    };


<table>
             <thead>
                <th>SUP NUMBER</th>
                <th>AIRLINE</th>
                <th>PRODUCT</th>
                <th>TITLE</th>
                <th>STATUS</th>
                <th>DATE HLE REQUEST RECEIVED</th>
                <th>HLE DEV (DAYS)</th>
                <th>HLE CLIENT (DAYS)</th>
                <th>DATE HLE SENT</th>
                <th>DATE HLE APPROVED / REFUSED</th>
                <th>COMMENTS</th>
                <th>EDIT ROW</th>
              </thead>

              <tbody>
                  {
                    WorkInProgressHLEsDataFilter()
                  }
              </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: The headers should be in separate table/div and table content it should be table inside div with overflow auto.

Comment: So 2 tables ? but then wouldn't they not be aligned?

Comment: Something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/wgmar5pk/ headers can be table too.

Comment: I will give this a try o.o thanks

Comment: Yeah, the problem with this is that the table headers won't align with the columns in each row :/

Comment: Set fixed width for cells so text will wrap. @bobb1213131

Answer (score 1):

`position: sticky` can be used in achieving this behavior.
You need to check this in the [browser demographic](https://caniuse.com/#search=position%3Asticky) you're looking to support and use a [polyfill](https://css-tricks.com/stickybits-alternative-position-sticky-polyfills/) where necessary.

The following snippet uses markup in the fiddle shared by @Zydnar

```css
.content-area {
  overflow-y: auto;
  height: 250px;
}

.body tr td {
  padding-top: 8px;
  padding-bottom: 4px;
}

.table {
  display: table;
}

.header {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  display: table-caption;
  top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="content-area">
  <table class="table">
    <thead class="header">
      <tr>
        <th>Header</th>
        <th>Header</th>
        <th>Header</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="body">
      <tr>
        <td>Content</td>
        <td>Content</td>
        <td>Content</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Content</td>
        <td>Content</td>
        <td>Content</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Content</td>
        <td>Content</td>
        <td>Content</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Content</td>
        <td>Content</td>
        <td>Content</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Content</td>
        <td>Content</td>
        <td>Content</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Content</td>
        <td>Content</td>
        <td>Content</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Content</td>
        <td>Content</td>
        <td>Content</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Content</td>
        <td>Content</td>
        <td>Content</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Content</td>
        <td>Content</td>
        <td>Content</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Content</td>
        <td>Content</td>
        <td>Content</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Content</td>
        <td>Content</td>
        <td>Content</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Content</td>
        <td>Content</td>
        <td>Content</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Content</td>
        <td>Content</td>
        <td>Content</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```